# Equivalent of getDataRange() to get range(s) with datavalidations?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where people copy/paste values. This causes them to bypass the data validations as it just "warns" them instead of rejecting the value.

I want to find all ranges in a sheet that have data validations. Tried to find something in the reference guide but it seems the only way to do this is to just loop over every cell and check for its data validations?

Would be great if someone has a more efficient way of checking this.

Comment: Do you know that you can set 'reject' option on data validation rule, like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYkTj.png ?

Comment: Yes, but try to paste invalid data in the sheet while you set it to reject. You'll find out that it does not reject the value in such case but gives a warning.

Comment: I see, looks like it is Sheets bug. You can add `onEdit` trigger to check cell has data validaton rule, then 'reject' pasted value by script.

Comment: I'd prefer to create a function to run daily that will move these entries to another tab in case of invalid entries. But thanks for thinking along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a loop, but not over cells (which would take an API call `getDataValidation` per cell) but over the double array returned by [getDataValidations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataValidations()):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
var rules = range.getDataValidations();
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < rules[0].length; j++) { 
    if (rules[i][j]) {
      // do something with the cell
    }
  }
}
```

There isn't a more direct method like `getNamedRanges` or `getProtections`.

Possible workaround: give names to the ranges that you want to validate, so you can retrieve them with `getNamedRanges`.